# ExpressJS authorizing users with middleware?

Tags: node.js, express

Let's say I want to restrict the access of a resource to a certain group of people who meet some conditions. What I'm doing right now is defining an authorization middleware that checks if the req.user is meeting those conditions.

```
module.exports.requiresCondition = function(req, res, next){
    Model.findOne({condition: condition}, function(err, model){
        //check if various conditions are met. If not, return 401
        res.locals.model = model;
        return next();
    }
}
```

The problem I have with this is that I can't choose what data to project because the routes that come after might use different parts of the model. This means I have to get the whole model every time, which becomes inefficient as the documents get larger and larger. Of course, I can just query once in the middleware with the keys I need to authorize and query again in the actual controller, but that doesn't seem particularly efficient either. Is there a better way to authorize users?

Comment: use passport-local module

Comment: I am using passport. But some resources belong only to certain users, and I don't want other people to be able to access them.

Answer (score 0):

If different routes require different data you can modularize your middleware layer. `composable-middelware` https://www.npmjs.com/package/composable-middleware is perfect for that.

So let's say you have couple of routes:

```js
import compose from 'composable-middleware';

router.get('/type1/:id', compose().use(Auth.hasAppAccess()).use(TypeMiddleware.getType1()), ctrl.doType1);
router.get('/type2/:id', compose().use(Auth.hasAppAccess()).use(TypeMiddleware.getType2()).use(TypeMiddleware.evenMoreOperations()), ctrl.doType2);
```

Then your middleware itself

```js
import compose from 'composable-middleware';

export function isAuthenticated() {
    return compose()
        .use(function(req, res, next) {
            //do your stuff here
        })
}

//similarly for other middelware functions
```